# Control width of samtools tview "snapshot" when redirecting

Tags: samtools, read-mapping, visualization

I have a large number of loci I would like to examine manually with `samtools tview`. Rather than typing or copy-n-pasting dozens of coordinates, I was hoping to automate the generation of pileup "images" (text files).

With some experimenting just now, I was happy to learn that if I specify the display option `-d H` or `-d T` the output can easily be redirected to a file for later inspection. However, it appears that I cannot control the window captured. Changing the width of the terminal window doesn't change the output, nor does adjusting the `-p` flag (i.e. `-p chr1:501-700`). No matter what, `tview` always reports an 80bp window in text or HTML mode.

Is there any way I can adjust this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cross-posted this question on the [official samtools issue tracker](https://github.com/samtools/samtools/issues/994), and finally got a response.

> Looking at the code for the HTML view, I see [this](https://github.com/samtools/samtools/blob/develop/bam_tview_html.c#L320) and [this](https://github.com/samtools/samtools/blob/develop/bam_tview_html.c#L348-L352).
>   So maybe try
>
> `COLUMNS=200 samtools tview -d H -p CHR:X-Y aln.bam ref.fasta`

Answer (score 2):

Partially a shameless plug. See if [ASCIIGenome](https://asciigenome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/description.html) can help you with that.

To review a number of regions that you saved in, say, a bed file, you can either process them in [batch](https://asciigenome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples.html#batch-and-non-interactive-mode) or load BAM(s) and bed file and jump from one bed interval to the next using the [`next -start`](https://asciigenome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/commandHelp.html#next) command.